# How to update a single item of liist of objects using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-update

I want like to update the `Value` of the list which has property `Text="ALL"`.

```cs
public class Season
    {
      public string Text {get;set;}
      public string Value {get;set;}
      public bool ValueSelected {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Question needs to be clarified. And here is a basic linq tutorial http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The 'Q' in LINQ stands for "Query". LINQ is not meant to update objects.

You can use LINQ to find the object you want to update and then update it "traditionally".

```
var toUpdate = _seasons.Single(x => x.Text == "ALL");

toUpdate.ValueSelected = true;
```

This code assumes that there is exactly *one* entry with `Text == "ALL"`. This code will throw an exception if there is none or if there are multiple.

If there is either none or one, use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
var toUpdate = _seasons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Text == "ALL");

if(toUpdate != null)
    toUpdate.ValueSelected = true;
```

If it's possible that there are multiple, use `Where`:

```
var toUpdate = _seasons.Where(x => x.Text == "ALL");

foreach(var item in toUpdate)
    item.ValueSelected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, as i was very new to development i could not post code properly. I have gone through the traditional approach

Comment: Well, the Q in SQL also stands for Query but SQL is used to update databases.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
// Initialize test list.
List<Season> seasons = new List<Season>();

seasons.Add(new Season()
{
    Text = "All"
});
seasons.Add(new Season()
{
    Text = "1"
});
seasons.Add(new Season()
{
    Text = "2"
});
seasons.Add(new Season()
{
    Text = "All"
});

// Get all season with Text set to "All".
List<Season> allSeasons = seasons.Where(se => se.Text == "All").ToList();

// Change all values of the selected seasons to "Changed".
allSeasons.ForEach(se => se.Value = "Changed");
```

Comment: I have only one Season Item With "ALL"  i want to Update only that Item , rest of the items are remains same