# How to change the value of a variable within a child of a nested list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Being new rather new to entity framework, LINQ and C#, I am not sure how to change the value of a variable in a nested list. I am aware that *LINQ is not meant to update objects*, but I read somewhere that you can do it somehow and that's what I am trying here. I am happy with any solution.

Assume we have two lists, `myData` with data of the current month, and `myDataBefore` with the same list from the previous month. I want to update `myData`. More specifically I want to change (in SQL you would say `UPDATE`) the `valuePrevMonth` and `deltaPercentage` for all 1st-level children inside that list - everything else should remain untouched. I tried the following, but this does not have the desired effect.

```cs
var myChildren = myData.SelectMany(x => x.children).ToList();
foreach (var child in myChildren)
  {
     var valuePrevMonth = myDataBefore.SelectMany(x => x.children)
                           .Where(x => (x.PositionId == child.PositionId && 
                                        x.SubPositionId == child.SubPositionId))
                           .Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
     // now comes the write-back step which I am probably messing up
     myData.SelectMany(x => x.children)
            .Where(x => (x.PositionId == child.PositionId &&
                         x.SubPositionId == child.SubPositionId))
            .Select(x => { 
                 x.previousValue = valuePrevMonth;
                 x.deltaPercentage = (x.Value - valuePrevMonth) / valuePrevMonth; // probably some IF-NULL check would not hurt
                 return x;
               }).ToList();
  }
```

The last `.Select(..)` is my current understanding how to update these two values of a given child object.

#### Some background

My nested list `List<myData>` is of following format (please allow me to use some kind of pseudocode for the definition):

```cs
myData 
    {
        int? PositionId 
        string PositionName 
        int SubPositionId 
        string SubPositionName
        myObject children 
        decimal? Value
        decimal? previousValue 
        decimal? deltaPercentage 
    }
```

#### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729289/8330162 - the quote that query means read-not-write comes from there
- [LINQ nested (inner) JOIN does not join children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079214/) - another question of mine which lead me to this problem here

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that your second statement beginning with `.SelectMany(x => x.Children)` may be unnecessary; if I'm reading it right, the thing you want to update is already in the `child` variable, so you would just do:

```
child.previousValue = valuePrevMonth;
...
```

That said, it may matter whether your `myObject` type is a `struct` or a `class`; if it's a `struct`, updating its fields will not do what you want, because you would be operating on a copy. To update elements of a List of `struct`s, you have to get the updated `struct` value that you want (e.g., by setting fields on a copy of the value), and then update the entire list element with `list[x] = updatedValue;`.