# How to update one element of a list without updating all elements in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with one piece of code and I was wondering if anyone could help me.

Here's my problem:

I'm working on a game and I created an inventory with a Dictionary. My Dictionary TKey is the item name and the TValue is a List. Each items has a boolean "isEquipped".

```
Dictionary<string, List<Item>> itemsInventory;
```

When equipping an item I want to check if the player has enough of this item and if this item can be equipped. I do that with this code:

```
public void EquipWeapon(bool tog, Item item)
{
    if (tog == true)
    {
        if (player.weapon == false)
        {
            player.GetStatByName(item.StatAffectedName).AddModifier(item.StatAffectedValue, StatModifier.ModifierOrigins.Equipment, StatModifier.ModifierType.Flat, item.AssetName);
            GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName && x.Value.Any(x => x.isEquiped == false)).Value.FirstOrDefault().isEquiped = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (player.weapon == true)
        {
            player.GetStatByName(item.StatAffectedName).RemoveModifier(item.AssetName);
            GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName && x.Value.Any(x => x.isEquiped == true)).Value.FirstOrDefault().isEquiped = false;
        }
        player.weapon = false;
    }
    player.GetStatByName(item.StatAffectedName).GetValue();
}
```

Problem with my code is that it changes all the items of the list and not just one.
Anyone could help me please?

Comment: How are you *creating* that list? Are you maybe inserting the same instance multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment you made *"If I update in the debugger it change all items as well."* it seems that the values in the list are the same object. This strongly suggests that `Item` is a `class` (not a `struct`).

You need to clone the objects before adding them to the list if they represent different instances.

From [Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types):

> With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable.

For completeness, you could use a value type (maybe something like `record struct` available from C#10):

> With value types, each variable has its own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one variable to affect the other (except in the case of in, ref and out parameter variables; see in, ref and out parameter modifier).

Answer (score 0):

Use linq to query out the list you want to update and then update the item of the list individually.
Use this as an example:
[How to update a single item of liist of objects using LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729239/how-to-update-a-single-item-of-liist-of-objects-using-linq-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm trying that but it still changes all the items ><
<code>var toUpdate = GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.Where(x => x.Key == "item.AssetName" && x.Value.Any(x => x.isEquiped == false)).FirstOrDefault().Value;
toUpdate[0].isEquiped = true;<c/ode>

Comment: have you debugged and checked if your toUpdate is as intended ?

Comment: Yes it gives me the list of item I want.

Comment: And in debug it shoes that all items of the list has changed

Comment: any before and after example would be helpful if you can share

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean. You want the new code? Because the new results are exactly the same.

Comment: `GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.Where(x => x.Key == "item.AssetName" && x.Value.Any(x => x.isEquiped == false)).FirstOrDefault().Value;` gives me the list I want.

`toUpdate[0].isEquiped = true;` should update the item at index 0 but when I'm checking the list after it stills shows that all items are now on true.

Comment: I know it is simple statement but try to divide that up too, try selecting the correct item from the list and then update it. See if it gives you correct item if you do something like var item = toUpdate[0];   item.isEquipped = true;

Comment: I tried but I still have the same error.

Comment: Hard to say the reasoning without seeing any output. Maybe you can share an example output of the query list on how it looks before and after setting first item to true.

Answer (score 0):

[image: List View]

[image: List's item detail]

After I changed from false to true not only the item at index 0 but all objects changes.

Comment: What if you update it in the debugger. Does this also change all items?

Comment: If I update in the debugger it change all items as well.

Comment: This means that the object in the list same object.

Comment: Hmm I see, so I need to change the way I'm adding the object to the list right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When I create the player, I create the Dictionary like this:

```
itemsInventory = new Dictionary<string, List<Item>>(),
```

And when I create the list it's like this:

```
Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.Add("weapon", new List<Item>());
Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.Add("armour", new List<Item>());
Instance.PlayerData.itemsInventory.Add("shield", new List<Item>());
```

Answer (score 0):

My code looked like this :

```
public void AddItemToInventory(Item? item, Ressource? ressource, int number = 1)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            int totalPrice = (item.Price * number);
            ressources.First(x => x.currency == item.Currency).amount -= totalPrice;
            DailyReportHandler.GetAndFillTodayReport().moneyForItems += totalPrice;
            if (itemsInventory.ContainsKey(item.AssetName))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName).Value.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                itemsInventory.Add(item.AssetName, new List<Item>());
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName).Value.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        if (ressource != null)
        {
            int totalPrice = (ressource.price * number);
            ressources.First(x => x.currency == Currency.credit).amount -= totalPrice;
            DailyReportHandler.GetAndFillTodayReport().moneyForItems += totalPrice;
            GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.AddResource(ressource.currency, number);
        }
    }
```

and I change it to this:

```
public void AddItemToInventory(Item? item, Ressource? ressource, int number = 1)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            int totalPrice = (item.Price * number);
            ressources.First(x => x.currency == item.Currency).amount -= totalPrice;
            DailyReportHandler.GetAndFillTodayReport().moneyForItems += totalPrice;
            if (itemsInventory.ContainsKey(item.AssetName))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName).Value.Add(GenerateNewItem(item));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                itemsInventory.Add(item.AssetName, new List<Item>());
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    itemsInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.AssetName).Value.Add(GenerateNewItem(item));
                }
            }
        }
        if (ressource != null)
        {
            int totalPrice = (ressource.price * number);
            ressources.First(x => x.currency == Currency.credit).amount -= totalPrice;
            DailyReportHandler.GetAndFillTodayReport().moneyForItems += totalPrice;
            GameManagerSingleton.Instance.PlayerData.AddResource(ressource.currency, number);
        }
    }
```

With `GenerateNewItem(item)` like this:

```
public Item GenerateNewItem(Item item)
    {
        var newItem = new Item
        {
            AssetName = item.AssetName,
            Currency = item.Currency,
            DescriptionLocalizationKey = item.AssetName,
            isEquiped = false,
            itemType = item.itemType,
            NameLocalizationKey = item.NameLocalizationKey,
            Price = item.Price,
            ShortDescriptionLocalizationKey = item.ShortDescriptionLocalizationKey,
            StatAffectedName = item.StatAffectedName,
            StatAffectedValue = item.StatAffectedValue
        };
        return newItem;
    }
```